# php PDO::FETCH_CLASS is mapping to all lowercase properties instead of camelCase

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following sample class that maps to a MySql table (shown below). When I use PDO::FETCH_CLASS and do a *var_dump* I see that the mapping is going to all lowercase properties. i.e. 'shortName' maps to 'shortname', but should be 'shortName' (camel case, like the defined property);

Why is it mapping to all lowercase and what can I do to map them to the exact sql name coming from the SELECT?

```
class Category {
  public $id;
  public $fkId;
  public $shortName;
  public $longName;

  public static function getCategories() {

    $db = ezcDbInstance::get();

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT 
                                 id, 
                                 fk_id AS `fkId`,
                                 short_name AS `shortName`,
                                 long_name As `longName`
                          FROM `Category`');

    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Category");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
$db = ezcDbInstance::get();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT...
```

to this:

```
$db = ezcDbInstance::get();
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL );

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ...
```

Comment: You might want to place the setAttribute before the execute() call as this is what is really influenced by this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that PDO does not support uppercase letters for the member variables.

As an alternative I suggest you map the data from the database to private members of your class and you provide getter and setters for access to them:

```
class Category
{
    private $shortname;

    ...

    public function getShortname()
    {
        return $this->shortname;
    }

    public function setShortname($name)
    {
        $name = (string) $name;
        if (!$name)
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Can\'t delete the name.');
        }
        $this->shortname = $name;
    }

    ...
}
```

This allows you to map the fields regardless of their name and you can control if a propery can be written to or not (like the ID). These shouldn't be public anyway.

You can further on improve this by moving the data access code into a base class and extend from it for your data classes like Category or however they will be named.

Comment: pretty much what I ended up doing. welcome to more ideas from others, but i'll mark this as answer for now.

Comment: You might find [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) insightful. More than one chapter is about how you can or could bring your database and your application together - with different kind of abstractions and mappings.