# Using mysql_fetch_assoc() to build inherited object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I've recently started using `mysql_fetch_object()` when looping through objects in my personally developed CMS.

I used to loop through using `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) { ... }`

and then I'd create an object and assign the values to it in the loop:

```
$object = new Object(); 
$object->set_by_row($row); // Does what it says
```

What i really want to do is use:

```
while ($object = mysql_fetch_object($rows, 'self')) { ... }
```

I hhve also tried using:

```
while ($image = mysql_fetch_object($rows, 'Image')) { ... } // Actual class name
```

But I can't! Most of my classes are subclasss of a parent class called Identifiable, which is a collection of variables and functions that apply to all my subclasses. It stores the ID of each object too - so when I use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, only the variables set in that class are set, not the associated parent variables.

Anybody know of a way to use `mysql_fetch_object` to set objects including their inherited variables?

Note: This is all within a static function within the subclass.

Here's a `var_dump` from after the assignment line:

```
object(Image)#5 (16) {
    ["title":"Image":private]=> string(0) ""
    ["location":"Image":private]=> string(0) ""
    ["description":"Image":private]=> string(0) ""
    ["file_name":"Image":private]=> string(14) "0_IMG_0984.JPG"
    ["original_x":"Image":private]=> string(4) "2592"
    ["original_y":"Image":private]=> string(4) "1944"
    ["type":"Image":private]=> string(3) "jpg"
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["added_by"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["updated_by"]=> string(1) "0"
    (...) ["deleted_by"]=> string(1) "0" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["published"]=> string(1) "0" ["datetime_added"]=> string(19) "2012-02-25 22:51:08" ["datetime_updated"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["datetime_deleted"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
}
```

As you can see, ID is in there, but my getter method is in the parent class, and returns nothing.

The getter method in the `Identifiable` class is here:

```
function get_id()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

---

CRITICAL UPDATE:

After I have set the object: `while ($image = mysql_fetch_object($rows, 'Image')) { ... }` I tried calling `echo $image->get_id();` and it works fine!

However, my problem still exists: I currently call a function in the loop (`get_interface_preview()`) that actually contains the call to `$this->get_id()` and that still returns nothing.

COMPLETE OVERHAUL!

My problem is here:

```
function get_interface_preview()
{
    echo $this->get_id();
    return "<a href='?a=edit&id='".$this->get_id()."'><img src='".IMAGE_PATH."library/admin_thumb/".$this->file_name."'></a>";
}
```

It echos the ID fine, but the ID isn't getting added to the markup.. I feel I have made a HUGE rookie mistake somehow?!

FIXED IT! I am so sorry everyone, this was an apostrophe in the wrong place! SO SORRY!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what your problem is? Which variable is (exemplary) not set? Loosely related: [php PDO::FETCH_CLASS is mapping to all lowercase properties instead of camelCase](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9438860/367456)

Comment: ID (belonging to the parent class) is not available to me in the current class after the function call.

Comment: Is `id` available to you? Can you show a `var_dump` of the class so it's probably more clear?

Comment: A var_dump where? in the static function that this belongs in?

Comment: Can you show the code of the getter function of the parent that is not working for you? Does `Image` extends from that parent class (just for clarification)?

Comment: Yes, `class Image extends Identifiable`

Comment: Sorry for asking so much, which PHP version are you using? What gives `echo PHP_VERSION;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an apostrophe in the wrong place. Feel free to throw humiliation my way!

Comment: you could consider migrating to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead of using the ancient `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 4):

You have to give it a class name, `'self'` is not a class name. Use [`get_class($this)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the class name of the current object, so:

```
while ($object = mysql_fetch_object($rows, get_class($this))) { ... }
```

Or, when in a static method, use `get_called_class()`:

```
while ($object = mysql_fetch_object($rows, get_called_class())) { ... }
```

See also [this PHP documentation contribution on a self-contained Singleton base class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php#86230)

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: this ...`

Comment: Using `get_called_class()` is the same as using 'self', and has the same result. Still can't access parent variables.

Comment: Then you are obviously not in an instance context. If this code is in a static method then use `get_called_class`, otherwise you need to find some other way to get hold of the class name.

Comment: You misunderstand me - in actual fact, the class is called 'Image'. When I use `while($image = mysql_fetch_object($rs, 'Image'))` Id is STILL not available.